# Why does this query return values in the column

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
  a.id, 
  c.c_date 
FROM table_a a , 
  table_c c
 WHERE 
  a.id = c.id AND 
  a.id IN (SELECT id from table_c where c_date is null);
```

I have two tables, `table_a` and `table_c`.

I join these two tables, but then get use an `IN` statement to only show the id's for in which are in `table_c` AND have the c_date column set to null`.

This query though returns `id, and c_date values, and some of the c_date values are not null`, **how is this possible?**

**I thought in my sub query I am only selecting id which have null c_dates?**

Comment: Maybe you have rows in `table_c` with same `id` but having differet `c_date` values (one of which is `NULL`).

Comment: [Avoid using the old-style `JOIN` syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Answer (score 2):

This should work without the subquery assuming you don't want to return `null` dates.  Please note the use of the `join`:

```
SELECT a.id, 
     c.c_date 
FROM table_a a 
    JOIN table_c c ON a.id = c.id  
WHERE c_date is null;
```

It's difficult to answer your specific question though without sample data and expected results.  You probably have multiple records in `table_c` that match the `id` field in `table_a`.

Comment: @user2924127 -- Depends on what you mean by you have a variable -- if that's another field in the table you could use an `outer join` with additional `where` criteria.  If it's literally a user defined variable, you could do the same or define an `if / else` block and remove the `join` altogether. Might be easier to post a new question for that...

Comment: Thanks for the answer @sgeddes, Yes I will post a new question for my followup question.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to explain with this example:

**table_a**

```
id  col_x  col_...
1   
2
```

**table_c**

```
id  c_date       col_m    col_...
1   null
1   03/14/2016
2   04/14/2016
```

You should consider review your intention on your result set. Change your query to @sgeddes answer is a way.